# JQuery Ajax call fails if contains javascript

Tags: jquery

Page using: jquery-1.8.0.min.js and jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js

```
$( '#d-select' ).click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        async: true,
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            a: 'get_popup',
            sb: 1
          },
                                                    success: function(txt){
            if (txt) {
                $( '#dialog' ).html(txt);
                $( '#dialog' ).dialog( 'open' );
            }else{
                alert('Problem generating popup');
            }
        }
    });
  });
```

txt returns HTML table with the following javascript:

```
<table><tr....................lots of data here</tr></table>
    <script language='JavaScript'>
                    <!--
                    function toggle(source) {
                      checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('changeD[]');
                      for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
                        checkbox.checked = source.checked;
                    }
                    //-->
                </script>
```

It works in all browsers except IE

I know its related to the following:
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9221

But dont know what to change to fix it..

Comment: <script language='JavaScript'>

Try 

<script type="text/javascript">

?

Comment: `for each` will only be supported for browsers that support Javascript 1.7 ... remove the `<!--` HTML comments and replace `language="JavaScript"` with `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: SCRIPT1005: Expected '(' 
index.php, line 4 character 11
SCRIPT257: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101. 
jquery-1.8.0.min.js, line 2 character 14033

Comment: @Mark Is it because IE does not support `for each`? Try changing it to normal `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(source) {
   checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('changeD[]');
   for(i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
      var checkbox=checkboxes[i];
      checkbox.checked = source.checked;
   }
}
</script>
```